# Is this an storage-reuse (aliasing) bug in gcc 6.2?

Tags: gcc, strict-aliasing

From what I can tell, the following code should have 100% defined behavior under any reasonable reading of the Standard for platforms which define `int64_t`, and where `long long` has the same size and representation, regardless of whether or not `long long` is recognized as alias-compatible.

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef long long T1;
typedef int64_t T2;
#define T1FMT "%lld"
#define T1VALUE 1
#define T2VALUE 2

T1 blah3(void *p1, void *p2)
{
  T1 *t1p, *t1p2;
  T2 *t2p;
  T1 temp;

  t1p = p1;
  t2p = p2;
  *t1p = T1VALUE;   // Write as T1
  *t2p = T2VALUE;   // Write as T2
  temp = *t2p;      // Read as T2
  t1p2 = (T1*)t2p;  // Visible T2 to T1 pointer conversion
  *t1p2 = temp;     // Write as T1
  return *t1p;      // Read as T1
}

T1 test3(void)
{
  void *p = malloc(sizeof (T1) + sizeof (T2));
  T1 result = blah3(p,p);
  free(p);
  return result;
}
int main(void)
{
  T1 result = test3();
  printf("The result is " T1FMT "\n", result);
  return 0;      
}
```

See code at https://godbolt.org/g/75oLGx (GCC 6.2 x86-64 using `-std=c99 -x c -O2`)

Correct code for `test3` should allocate some storage, then:

1. Writes a `long long` with value 1.
2. Sets the Effective Type of the storage to `int64_t` by writing an `int64_t` with value 2.
3. Reads the storage as `int64_t` (its Effective Type), which should yield 2
4. Sets the effective type of the storage to `long long` by storing the a `long long` with the aforementioned value (which should be 2).
5. Read the storage as type `long long`, which should yield 2.

The gcc x86-64 6.2 at the godbolt site, however, does not yield 2; instead it yields 1.  I didn't find any other combination of types for which gcc behaves
like this.  I think what's happening is that gcc is deciding that the store to *t1p2 can be omitted because it has no effect, but it's failing to recognize that the store did have the effect of changing the Effective Type of the storage from `int64_t` to `long long`.

While I consider questionable the decision not to recognize `int64_t` and `long long` as being alias-compatible, I see nothing in the Standard that would justify gcc's failure to recognize the reuse of the storage to hold the value 2 after it had previously held the value 1.  Nothing is ever read as any type other than the one with which it was written, but I think gcc is deciding that the two pointers passed to "blah" can't alias.

Am I missing anything or is that an outright bug?

Answer (score 0):

The code does not violate the strict aliasing rule, as you explain.  In fact, `T1` and `T2` could be any types (such that the assignments are not type mismatches), there's no need for them to have the same size or anything.

I would agree that outputting `1` is a compiler bug. On the godbolt site, all versions of gcc seem to have the bug, whereas clang gives the correct output.

However, with a local installation of gcc 4.9.2 (x86_64-win32-seh-rev1), I get the correct output of 2.  So it seems that the problem only exists in some builds of gcc.

Comment: A key condition for the bug to appear, so far as I can tell, is that the compiler must (incorrectly) regard the store to `*t1p2` as a no-op.  I don't know whether all installations of gcc use the same definition for `int64_t`, since on a platform where that type is specified as `long long`, the code here would work fine as shown here, but would fail if T1 were changed to `long`.  I wonder if the authors of the Standard ever intended that any quality compiler wouldn't recognize aliasing between types with the same size and representation, since failure to recognize it can make it very hard...

Comment: ...to exchange data in defined fashion between APIs which use different named types for the same data format?  In any case, I think what's going on is that gcc decides the write as `T2` can't affect `*t1p` because of its type, and the write as `T1` can't affect it because it's simply writing what was "already written" (even though the previous write got ignored).

Comment: @supercat seems plausible, I guess that could be confirmed by diving into the optimizer code